# How to increase width of an Alert component in Ionic4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I would like to know, how can i increase width of an Alert Controller in ionic4.

I have tried many techniques but haven't succeeded in any. I have created a stackblitz example for clarity. Here i have button on click of which, the alert appears but i want the alert to be more broad. I have also added a css variable to change the width but it also doesn't work

`ion-alert{
  --width: 400px;
}`

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-96nusz)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your StackBlitz, I did this in your `index.html`

```
<style>
  div.alert-wrapper {
    width: 700px; // play with this number
  }
</style>
<ion-app></ion-app>
```

But in your application itself, you should have a `styles.scss` or `main.scss` to add global styles like this. You should put this style there.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your `global.scss` or `app.component.scss`

```
::ng-deep .alert-wrapper {
    width: 1000px;  # or whatever sized width you prefer
}
```